# compare foreign language strings in scilab

Tags: scilab

I am trying to compare the input string with the strings present in the doc. I am using `strcmp` for the purpose. These are non-English strings. When the input string is English language, the output is correct. But for any Kannada (non-English language) word the output is the same. I am trying to write a program to check if the word is present in the database. Please guide me in what could be the problem.

The calling function is as below:

```
str_kan = handles.InputBox.String;

res = strcmp('str_kan','s1.text')
if res == 1 then handles.InputBox.String = string( ' present')
    abort
else
     handles.InputBox.String = string( 'not present')
     abort
end
```

The whole program is as below:

```
global s1

f=figure('figure_position',[400,50],'figure_size',[640,480],'auto_resize','on','background',[33],'figure_name','Graphic window number %d','dockable','off','infobar_visible','off','toolbar_visible','off','menubar_visible','off','default_axes','on','visible','off');

handles.dummy = 0;
handles.InputBox=uicontrol(f,'unit','normalized','BackgroundColor',[-1,-1,-1],'Enable','on','FontAngle','normal','FontName','Tunga','FontSize',[12],'FontUnits','points','FontWeight','normal','ForegroundColor',[-1,-1,-1],'HorizontalAlignment','left','ListboxTop',[],'Max',[1],'Min',[0],'Position',[0.0929487,0.6568182,0.4647436,0.1795455],'Relief','default','SliderStep',[0.01,0.1],'String','Enter a Kannada Word','Style','edit','Value',[0],'VerticalAlignment','middle','Visible','on','Tag','InputBox','Callback','')
handles.CheckDB=uicontrol(f,'unit','normalized','BackgroundColor',[-1,-1,-1],'Enable','on','FontAngle','normal','FontName','Tahoma','FontSize',[12],'FontUnits','points','FontWeight','normal','ForegroundColor',[-1,-1,-1],'HorizontalAlignment','center','ListboxTop',[],'Max',[1],'Min',[0],'Position',[0.1025641,0.4636364,0.4567308,0.1204545],'Relief','default','SliderStep',[0.01,0.1],'String','Check','Style','pushbutton','Value',[0],'VerticalAlignment','middle','Visible','on','Tag','CheckDB','Callback','CheckDB_callback(handles)')

f.visible = "on";

function CheckDB_callback(handles)
str_kan = handles.InputBox.String;

res = strcmp('str_kan','s1.text')
if res == 1 then handles.InputBox.String = string( ' present')
    abort
else
     handles.InputBox.String = string( 'not present')
     abort
end


endfunction
```

Comment: Try `strcmp(str_kan,s1.text)` and not `strcmp('str_kan','s1.text')`

Comment: also this is not the whole code as `s1` is a global variable not defined here. Please provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks PTRK for your comment. I found and confirmed that Scilab does not support unicode and that is the reason for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example showing that, in Scilab, strcmp() **does support** UTF-8 extended characters:

```
--> strcmp(["aα" "aα" "aβ"], ["aα" "aβ" "aα"])
 ans  =
   0.  -1.   1.
```

The problem in the original posted code is the confusion between literal values as `"Hello"` and variables names as `Hello="my text"`, as already noted by PTRK.